# Quickly read numeric input

Tags: performance, c, parsing, io, integer

Do you have any criticisms or corrections or improvements?

I need to read only **numbers**(and this numbers could be from 0 to 1000000)

```
void fast_input(int* int_input)
  {
      *int_input=0;
       char next_char=0;
          while( next_char < '0' || next_char > '9' ){ // Skip non-digits
              next_char = getchar();
              }
              while( next_char >= '0' && next_char <= '9' )
              {
                  (*int_input) = ((*int_input)<<1) + ((*int_input)<<3) + next_char - '0';
                  next_char = getchar();
              }
 
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you have any criticisms or corrections or improvements?

**Infinite loop**

On end-of-file, first `while` loops loops forever.

Better code would prevent looping forever and return not `void`, but an indication of success.

**`int` vs. `char`**

`getchar()` returns an `int` and typically 257 different values.  Saving in a `char` will lose information.  Save in an `int` to properly distinguish `EOF` from other characters.

**Avoid trying to out-think the compiler**

A good compiler will emit optimal code.

```
// (*int_input) = ((*int_input)<<1) + ((*int_input)<<3) + next_char - '0';
*int_input = *int_input * 10 +  + next_char - '0';
```

***Fast* vs. I/O**

Input/Output is a sink-hole of time. Significant time improvement are made there, not in trying to using `<` instead of `*`.

**On return, restore last character read**

To better work with other routines, it is more common to `ungetc()` the last non-digit read.

**No overflow protection**

Signed `int` overflow is *undefined behavior* (UB).

Yes, OP has "need to read only numbers(and this numbers could be from 0 to 1000000)", but that limitation is not commented in the code.  So the next person lifts this code and runs into UB.

Comment  important restrictions in code.

Even better, detect potential overflow

```
int ch = getchar();
if (*int_input >= INT_MAX/10 && 
    (*int_input > INT_MAX/10 || ch - '0' > INT_MAX%10)) {
  // Overflow!
  *int_input = INT_MAX;
} else {
  *int_input = *int_input * 10 +  + next_char - '0';
}
```

**Consider a local variable**

```
int sum = 0;
... most of code
*int_input = sum;
```

**Minor: 2 compares vs. `isdigit()`**

Consider `isdigit()` rather than 2 compares.

**Poor formatting**

---

**Alternative**

Untested - but at least gives OP an idea of the above feedback.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Return EOF on end-of-file or input error without reading an int.
// Return 0 on overflow.  Value is capped.
// Return 1 on success.
// Save value read if int_input is not NULL
int fast_input_alt(int *int_input) {
  int sum = 0;
  int ch;

  // Skip non-digits
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && !isdigit(ch)) {
    ;
  }

  if (ch == EOF) {
    return EOF;
  }

  int retval = 1;
  do {
    ch -= '0';
    if (sum >= INT_MAX / 10 && (sum > INT_MAX / 10 || ch > INT_MAX % 10)) {
      sum = INT_MAX;
      retval = 0;  // Overflow
    } else {
      sum = sum * 10 + ch;
    }
    ch = getchar();
  } while (isdigit(ch));

  ungetc(ch, stdin);
  if (int_input) {
    *int_input = sum;
  }
  return retval;
}
```